# Info on using 'retry' command in google CTS

Tags: android, cts

I'm new to CTS and my test stops after executing 83 modules out of 218 on my box that i'm running the test. Tried multiple times running the test and each time test stop exactly at same point.

```
06-08 19:24:49 I/ConsoleReporter: [6.2.200.123:5555] armeabi-v7a CtsSelinuxTargetSdkTestCases completed in 210 ms. 1 passed, 0 failed, 0 not executed
06-08 19:24:55 W/CompatibilityTest: Inaccurate runtime hint for armeabi-v7a CtsSelinuxTargetSdkTestCases, expected 2m 0s was 31s
06-08 19:24:59 I/ConsoleReporter: [6.2.200.123:5555] Starting armeabi-v7a CtsSyncContentHostTestCases with 3 tests
06-08 19:25:33 W/NativeDevice: Did not detect device 6.2.200.123:5555 becoming unavailable after reboot
06-08 19:25:33 W/NativeDevice: AdbCommandRejectedException (device offline) when attempting shell id on device 6.2.200.123:5555
06-08 19:25:39 E/NativeDeviceStateMonitor: device offline
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:973)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:508)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:387)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:616)
```

When i run indudial module - 'CtsSyncContentHostTestCases' test did pass with 3 out of 3 PASS

I now want to continue my test where it was halted before and trying to use retry command.

Where do i look for session id to retry in below command line ?

```
 retry --retry <session id to retry> [--retry-type <FAILED | NOT_EXECUTED>]
```

Would help if an example is posted on retry as i'm new to CTS

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
run retry
```

> For Android 9 and higher only. Retry all the tests that failed or **weren't executed from the previous sessions**. For example, run retry --retry -s or run retry --retry --shard-count with TF sharding. run cts --retry isn't allowed for Android 9 and higher.

```
run cts --retry
```

> For Android 8

```
run cts --retry session_id
```

> Retry all tests that failed or were not executed from the previous sessions. Use `list results` to get the **session id**.

---

CTS-test are a bit flaky, and has to be rerun multiple times, and there is some [preconditions](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/setup) that needs to be fulfilled that needs to be met before you execute an CTS-test, like *factory reset* or having *wifi on*.

Comment: Was able to see 'session' column using 'list results command. Thanks much!!

Comment: I'm using Android 8 so retry command wont help i believe. any alternate command that i can try ?

Comment: Try this: `run cts --retry`

Answer (score 0):

You can see all your sessions id's, buy typing list results:

```
cts-tf > l r
```

After that you can continue your testing buy typing session id number as mentioned in post above.